# insert the null record in the print lable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a SP which print the label of my vendor, vendor name. I want the user set the startposition, before the startposition I just simply insert a null value. I want be able to reuse the label sheet.

I have the SP code like this:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[z_sp_APVendorLabel]
    (@VendorGroup bGroup ,
     @StartPosition int)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Create table #data_null
    (Vendor int,
     Name varchar(60)null)

Declare @counter int
SET @counter = 0
WHILE @counter <  @StartPosition
BEGIN
     UPDATE #data_null  SET Vendor='',Name=' '
     SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

Create table #detial
(Vendor int,
 Name varchar (60)null)

 select Vendor, Name into  #data from APVM 
 WHERE VendorGroup= @VendorGroup

select * from #data_null
Union All
select * from #detial


END
```

It is very simple, but when I test it, I did not get any data.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server management studio

Comment: I don't see a definition for #data. Do you mean #detail? Are you sure there are rows in APVM that satisfy your filter (VendorGroup = @VendorGroup)?

Comment: i have two table, #data_null get the null record, i want add the null records  certain times, #detail table get the record from APVM, Then i union the two tables

Comment: yes, it is #detail table. I can not believe it, it wasted my whole afternoon. thanks

Comment: What about this bGroup type in your params...?? explain it pls XD

Comment: @user1723572, Don't worry, we've all done it. Just bang your head against the wall a few times and get back to work. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the table `#data_null`, and updating it, but never inserting any rows.  If you inspect `@@rowcount` after each update, you'll see it's zero.

Before you change that loop to `insert` instead of `update`, please consider setting up a permanent table to select from.  A loop to generate N values on every invocation of the procedure is really not the best use of your server's time, or yours.  ;-)